# Dúvida quanto a marcação "volumes" dentro do docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker

O docker-compose.yml abaixo foi retirado da própria documentação do docker. Minha dúvida é: por qual motivo dentro do container db temos a referencia de volumes e no final do arquivo a mesma referência se repete? O que significa?

```
version: '3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress

volumes:
    db_data:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `db_data` é uma referencia para um volume definido dentro do seu `docker-compose.yml`. Dentro do service `db` ele está indicando que deve salvar os dados em um volume interno gerenciado pelo Docker (e não em um *path* mapeado no seu disco).

```
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

No final do arquivo temos a declaração desse volume, onde você pode indicar de onde a referencia do `db_data` deve apontar. No arquivo está a declaração reduzida, mas aquele final pode ser definido também da seguinte forma:

```
volumes:
    db_data:
        driver: local
```

É possível definir opções extras dependendo do caso:

```
volumes:
    db_data:
        driver: local
        name: my_volume_name
        external: true
```

Consulte a [documentação](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference) para ver as possíveis opções.

Lembrando que essa referencia não é a mesma utilizada para o nome do volume para o Docker. Para isso temos a propriedade `name`, caso contrário esse volume seguira a convenção `<path_do_projeto>_<referencia_do_volume>`.

Exemplo:

```
> docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME   
local               wordpress_db_data
```

Com `name` definido:

```
> docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME   
local               my_volume_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Embora seja comum deixar essas informações no final, a ordem realmente é indiferente. Os elementos principais (que estão na raíz do yaml) Networks e Volumes são usados para especificar recursos, respectivamente redes e volumes.

Essa forma de estruturar reafirma a segurança de que você só irá usar volumes ou redes que previamente definiu. A definição destas é global para o seu yaml.

> Somente após especificados estes podem ser usados nos
>   serviços/containers. Esse modelo se dá pois além do nome (como vemos
>   no caso do volume) podemos definir driver e outras informações, em
>   contrapartida podemos reaproveitar um mesmo volume em diversos
>   containers.

Comment: Então essa marcação de volumes no escopo global é uma definição, ou seja, uma marcação de que o volume será obrigatoriamente usado. Certo? É opcional essa marcação global?

Comment: Não é somente uma marcação, é a definição. Que pode inclusive ser um volume externo (que não está sendo criado no seu compose, mas foi criado previamente).

Comment: E não é opcional